# Is there a way to draw a SCNNode always in front of others?

Tags: swift, scenekit, scnnode

I've been trying to make a scene with scene kit in which an specified object is always in front of others, despite the fact that it's actually behind the other objects. A similar effect to this used in [blender](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iHgXq.png).

Apparently, blender uses GUI and a lot of math to transform otherwise 2D objects, but I need this effect in a SCNNode with a SCNGeometry, in other words, a 3D object currently locate in the scene.

I considered using category masks, but after reading Apple's documentation I've realized that doesn't work for the effect I'm looking for.

Does anyone know a way of doin this in SceneKit? Or better yet, is it even possible to do this?

Thank you all so much in advance, for now and all other help I've got from StackExchange!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As explained in my previous answer, the accepted answer isn't optimal and works properly only for billboards, huds and other generally flat objects (not necessarily entirely 2D). When using 3D objects and disabling reading from the depth buffer and objects like the one in the image in above, it won't render correctly from every angle. I.e a 3D object *needs* to read from the depth buffer to detect its own pixels and depth. That all said, I present the correct answer:

[SCNTechnique](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/scenekit/scntechnique)

In short, render 2 additional passes. One for the control gizmo (DRAW_NODE), and one to mix it together with the scene by another pass (DRAW_QUAD, with a shader that uses the previous passes as inputs).

Following is the techique's scntec.plist contents:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>passes</key>
    <dict>
        <key>gizmoonly</key>
        <dict>
            <key>colorStates</key>
            <dict>
                <key>clear</key>
                <true/>
                <key>clearColor</key>
                <string>0.5 0.5 0.5 0.0</string>
            </dict>
            <key>depthStates</key>
            <dict>
                <key>clear</key>
                <true/>
            </dict>
            <key>inputs</key>
            <dict>
                <key>colorSampler</key>
                <string>COLOR</string>
            </dict>
            <key>outputs</key>
            <dict>
                <key>color</key>
                <string>gizmonode</string>
            </dict>
            <key>draw</key>
            <string>DRAW_NODE</string>
            <key>node</key>
            <string>movegizmo</string>
        </dict>
        <key>quadscene</key>
        <dict>
            <key>colorStates</key>
            <dict>
                <key>clear</key>
                <true/>
                <key>clearColor</key>
                <string>sceneBackground</string>
            </dict>
            <key>depthStates</key>
            <dict>
                <key>clear</key>
                <true/>
            </dict>
            <key>inputs</key>
            <dict>
                <key>totalSceneO</key>
                <string>COLOR</string>
                <key>a_texcoord</key>
                <string>a_texcoord-symbol</string>
                <key>gizmoNodeO</key>
                <string>gizmonode</string>
            </dict>
            <key>outputs</key>
            <dict>
                <key>color</key>
                <string>COLOR</string>
            </dict>
            <key>draw</key>
            <string>DRAW_QUAD</string>
            <key>program</key>
            <string>gizmo</string>
        </dict>
    </dict>
    <key>sequence</key>
    <array>
        <string>gizmoonly</string>
        <string>quadscene</string>
    </array>
    <key>targets</key>
    <dict>
        <key>totalscene</key>
        <dict>
            <key>type</key>
            <string>color</string>
        </dict>
        <key>gizmonode</key>
        <dict>
            <key>type</key>
            <string>color</string>
        </dict>
    </dict>
    <key>symbols</key>
    <dict>
        <key>a_texcoord-symbol</key>
        <dict>
            <key>semantic</key>
            <string>texcoord</string>
        </dict>
        <key>vertexSymbol</key>
        <dict>
            <key>semantic</key>
            <string>vertex</string>
        </dict>
    </dict>
</dict>
</plist>
```

Following is the vertex shader for the second pass:

```
attribute vec4 a_position;
varying vec2 uv;

void main() {
    gl_Position = a_position;
    uv = (a_position.xy + 1.0) * 0.5;
}
```

The fragment shader for the second pass:

```
uniform sampler2D totalSceneO;
uniform sampler2D gizmoNodeO;

varying vec2 uv;

void main() {
    vec4 t0 = texture2D(totalSceneO, uv);
    vec4 t1 = texture2D(gizmoNodeO, uv);
    gl_FragColor = (1.0 - t1.a) * t0 + t1.a * t1;
}
```

Swift code:

```
if let path = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("scntec", ofType: "plist") {
            if let dico1 = NSDictionary(contentsOfFile: path)  {
                let dico = dico1 as! [String : AnyObject]

                let technique = SCNTechnique(dictionary:dico)
                scnView.technique = technique
            }
}
```

Objective-C code:

```
NSURL *url = [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:@"scntec" withExtension:@"plist"];
SCNTechnique *technique = [SCNTechnique techniqueWithDictionary:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithContentsOfURL:url]];
    self.myView.technique = technique;
```

Set the name for the gizmo node:

```
theGizmo.name = @"movegizmo";
```

Comment: I know this is quite old.  But can you tell me how do you use the 2 shader.  Are they in 2 different files?  How and when are the loaded ?  Can you please help?

Answer (score 6):

So, turns out I found the answer to my question (with the help of mnuages). I just wanted to post a complete answer.

[image: Final result]

Like suggested by mnuages, I tried setting both `readsFromDepthBuffer` and `writesToDepthBuffer` to false and setting the node's `renderingOrder` to a high number. It worked the wrong way. Instead of being always in front, it was always behind every object. The way to get the result shown in the picture is to set only `readsFromDepthBuffer` to false, and set the cube's `renderingOrder` to -1, or else it will be impossible to draw over it.

Since the cube and the other nodes' materials have `readsFromDepthBuffer` and `writesToDepthBuffer` set to the default value of `true`, it will still be in front of the objects behind it, and behind the objects in front of it, in other words, it will be normal, only the arrows will behave the way we want.

As can be seen in the image, the portion of the lines in front of the cube are visible. The same can't be said for portion behind it.

***Edit:*** *This only worked for me because in my case the camera did not have to rotate around the object. It will not work if you need the gizmo to be always in front regardless of the camera angle. Check the accepted answer for an explanation on how to achieve that, additionally, simeon's answer for a Metal implementation.*

Comment: That fits with [Apple's documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/SceneKit/Reference/SCNMaterial_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/SCNMaterial/writesToDepthBuffer) for `writesToDepthBuffer` and `readsFromDepthBuffer`. The main use case for `writesToDepthBuffer` seems to be for handling transparency. I've found that an object with transparency can cause objects behind it to vanish from some angles unless `writesToDepthBuffer` is set to false for the transparent object's SCNMaterial. Even then I've seen a few glitches, but this definitely helped.

Comment: It's perhaps wandering off topic a little to add to my previous comment, but it turns out that setting `renderingOrder` to -1 on my transparent object fixed remaining render issues.

Comment: That's a little senseless to me, I mean, the documentation suggests that simply setting an object's `renderingOrder` to a bigger number and combining it with the proper depth buffer setting would work, but apparently an object with its material's `readFromDepthBuffer` property set to false will only be in front of other objects if said objects have a negative `renderingOrder`.

Comment: Keep in mind (as noted by Xartec) that this technique will only work in cases similar to mine in which the scene will always be visible from the same angle only.

Comment: Thanks for this. I was using billboard constraint, and in my case, I had to set "readsFromDepthBuffer" false to all nodes, and set rendering order to be descending order: 0 for the first one to draw, and subsequent ones were -1, -2, -3, etc.

Comment: Comment for the Edit: You can set the materials transparency to a non opaque value for example 0.99. Then the rendering goes through some additional render passes where the ordering is solved thus the arrows will overlap correctly. This is a simple hack which in some cases won't be feasible.

Answer (score 4):

@Xartec's answer is the way to go. You basically render the gizmo alone, on a transparent background, then use a simple shader to mix it with the scene. Here's the same setup for Metal

Gizmo.metal

```
#include <metal_stdlib>
using namespace metal;

#include <SceneKit/scn_metal>

struct custom_vertex_t
{
    float4 position [[attribute(SCNVertexSemanticPosition)]];
    float4 normal [[attribute(SCNVertexSemanticNormal)]];
};

struct out_vertex_t
{
    float4 position [[position]];
    float2 uv;
};

vertex out_vertex_t gizmo_vertex(custom_vertex_t in [[stage_in]])
{
    out_vertex_t out;
    out.position = in.position;
    out.uv = float2((in.position.x + 1.0) * 0.5 , (in.position.y + 1.0) * -0.5);

    return out;
};

constexpr sampler s = sampler(coord::normalized,
                              r_address::clamp_to_edge,
                              t_address::repeat,
                              filter::linear);

fragment half4 gizmo_fragment(out_vertex_t vert [[stage_in]],
                              texture2d<float, access::sample> totalSampler [[texture(0)]],
                              texture2d<float, access::sample> gizmoSampler [[texture(1)]])
{

    float4 t0 = totalSampler.sample(s, vert.uv);
    float4 t1 = gizmoSampler.sample(s, vert.uv);

    return half4((1.0 - t1.a) * t0 + t1.a * t1);
}
```

GizmoTechnique.plist

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>passes</key>
    <dict>
        <key>pass_scene</key>
        <dict>
            <key>draw</key>
            <string>DRAW_SCENE</string>
            <key>inputs</key>
            <dict/>
            <key>outputs</key>
            <dict>
                <key>color</key>
                <string>color_scene</string>
            </dict>
            <key>colorStates</key>
            <dict>
                <key>clear</key>
                <true/>
                <key>clearColor</key>
                <string>sceneBackground</string>
            </dict>
        </dict>
        <key>pass_gizmo</key>
        <dict>
            <key>colorStates</key>
            <dict>
                <key>clear</key>
                <true/>
                <key>clearColor</key>
                <string>0 0 0 0</string>
            </dict>
            <key>depthStates</key>
            <dict>
                <key>clear</key>
                <true/>
            </dict>
            <key>outputs</key>
            <dict>
                <key>color</key>
                <string>color_gizmo</string>
            </dict>
            <key>inputs</key>
            <dict/>
            <key>draw</key>
            <string>DRAW_NODE</string>
            <key>node</key>
            <string>transformGizmo</string>
        </dict>
        <key>mix</key>
        <dict>
            <key>colorStates</key>
            <dict>
                <key>clear</key>
                <true/>
            </dict>
            <key>depthStates</key>
            <dict>
                <key>clear</key>
                <true/>
            </dict>
            <key>inputs</key>
            <dict>
                <key>totalSampler</key>
                <string>COLOR</string>
                <key>gizmoSampler</key>
                <string>color_gizmo</string>
            </dict>
            <key>outputs</key>
            <dict>
                <key>color</key>
                <string>COLOR</string>
            </dict>
            <key>draw</key>
            <string>DRAW_QUAD</string>
            <key>program</key>
            <string>doesntexist</string>
            <key>metalFragmentShader</key>
            <string>gizmo_fragment</string>
            <key>metalVertexShader</key>
            <string>gizmo_vertex</string>
        </dict>
    </dict>
    <key>sequence</key>
    <array>
        <string>pass_gizmo</string>
        <string>mix</string>
    </array>
    <key>targets</key>
    <dict>
        <key>color_gizmo</key>
        <dict>
            <key>type</key>
            <string>color</string>
        </dict>
    </dict>
    <key>symbols</key>
    <dict>
        <key>vertexSymbol</key>
        <dict>
            <key>semantic</key>
            <string>vertex</string>
        </dict>
    </dict>
</dict>
</plist>
```

Comment: Your answer seems simpler, but it is derived from Xartec's original answer. So I'm accepting his, and upvoting yours.

Comment: Works like a charm. Since I'm using this inside of a framework, I had to add this line of code in order to correctly load the Metal library: `scnView.technique!.library = try! view.device!.makeDefaultLibrary(bundle: frameworkBundle)`.

Answer (score 2):

The readsFromDepthBuffer answer may work for the angle in the the image shown but if you were to rotate and look at different angles you will see the gizmo's axis overlap incorrectly from some angles. In other words some axis will be behind another when it should be in front of it, depending on which order the faces are rendered. This is obviously because the object (material) doesnt read the depth buffer, including for parts it already rendered of itself.

In general an easy solution to render a SCNNode in front of the main scene is to use an SK3DNode (with its own scene and depthbuffer) in the scene's overlaySKScene. For the scenario shown in the picture in the answer this would require additional code to rotate and position the SK3DNode accurately so it's probably not what the OP was looking for but this may be of help to others who find this question.

Answer (score 1):

`SCNMaterial` exposes `writesToDepthBuffer` and `readsFromDepthBuffer` that will let you do that (in combination with `SCNNode`'s `renderingOrder` if necessary)

Comment: I've finally managed to check out what you said. In fact, setting the options you said from it's default True value to False, seems to be the solution, as I've managed to get my obect to be drawn always in front of some others, but not all. I have yet to figure out how to work the rendering order, because there is something I am doing wrong. But thank you :)

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if it is of any help, but I happily just found out, that the method Apple described in their documentation actually works out nicely.
I have an object which is supposed to be shown permanently and in front of all the others. Setting its rendering order (node inspector) to higher values (yet all the same for said nodes) and unchecking the ‚reads depth‘ checkbox (Material inspector) for all used materials leads to the desired result.
The rendering order of all other objects is kept at zero, no negative order applied.
I understood you need this in code, but maybe you can make something out of this?

Comment: Thank you! But five years ago when I did try that it didn't work. I found an unideal solution which didn't quite work if the camera rotated, but back then I didn't need the camera to rotate around it. These days I can't even verify your suggestion since I no longer own a Mac. I'll upvote you answer and hope it can help others.