# ARKit Rendering an object silhouette when behind other objects using SCNTechnique

Tags: ios, swift, scenekit, arkit, metal

I want to render a gizmo object in my ARKit app so that it is still visible behind other geometry, but as a darkened silhouette. The Unity shader I found [here](https://forum.unity.com/threads/turn-transparent-when-behind-wall-how-to-do-this.36238/) produces the effect I am trying to reproduce in SceneKit/ARKit.

I've been looking into using SCNTechnique, and have been using the example described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56740597/12454116). I have modified the example slightly, but the general gist is a 3 pass shader:

1. First pass renders the whole scene (draw: `DRAW_SCENE`)
2. second pass renders just parts of the gizmo where gizmo depth is greater than scene depth (draw: `DRAW_SCENE` with `includeCategoryMask` of the gizmo).
3. mix the outputs of the first and second passes so that the hidden parts rendered in pass 2 darken pass 1.

Pass 1 is working correctly, as the whole scene is rendered as expected with a black background (as set in the `colorStates`). However, no matter what I try, in pass 2 the colorStates' "clear" property is always ignored. I want pass 2 to have a black background like pass 1, but it always outputs the camera feed from ARKit. This causes a problem in pass 3 where I cannot correctly blend the colours because pass 2 contains all the camera feed detail, where it should be black. I'm not sure if this is a bug in ARKit, or I am misunderstanding SCNTechniques, but any help would be massively appreciated.

Here is my SCNTechnique:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>passes</key>
    <dict>
        <key>pass_scene</key>
        <dict>
            <key>colorStates</key>
            <dict>
                <key>clearColor</key>
                <string>0 0 0 1</string>
                <key>clear</key>
                <true/>
            </dict>
            <key>draw</key>
            <string>DRAW_SCENE</string>
            <key>inputs</key>
            <dict/>
            <key>outputs</key>
            <dict>
                <key>depth</key>
                <string>DEPTH</string>
                <key>color</key>
                <string>color_scene</string>
            </dict>
        </dict>
        <key>pass_gizmo</key>
        <dict>
            <key>includeCategoryMask</key>
            <integer>2</integer>
            <key>colorStates</key>
            <dict>
                <key>clearColor</key>
                <string>0 0 0 1</string>
                <key>clear</key>
                <true/>
            </dict>
            <key>depthStates</key>
            <dict>
                <key>func</key>
                <string>greater</string>
                <key>enableWrite</key>
                <false/>
                <key>clear</key>
                <false/>
            </dict>
            <key>outputs</key>
            <dict>
                <key>depth</key>
                <string>DEPTH</string>
                <key>color</key>
                <string>color_gizmo</string>
            </dict>
            <key>inputs</key>
            <dict>
                <key>color</key>
                <string>color_gizmo</string>
            </dict>
            <key>draw</key>
            <string>DRAW_SCENE</string>
        </dict>
        <key>mix</key>
        <dict>
            <key>colorStates</key>
            <dict>
                <key>clear</key>
                <true/>
            </dict>
            <key>depthStates</key>
            <dict>
                <key>clear</key>
                <false/>
            </dict>
            <key>inputs</key>
            <dict>
                <key>totalSampler</key>
                <string>color_scene</string>
                <key>gizmoSampler</key>
                <string>color_gizmo</string>
            </dict>
            <key>outputs</key>
            <dict>
                <key>color</key>
                <string>COLOR</string>
            </dict>
            <key>draw</key>
            <string>DRAW_QUAD</string>
            <key>program</key>
            <string>doesntexist</string>
            <key>metalFragmentShader</key>
            <string>gizmo_fragment</string>
            <key>metalVertexShader</key>
            <string>gizmo_vertex</string>
        </dict>
    </dict>
    <key>sequence</key>
    <array>
        <string>pass_scene</string>
        <string>pass_gizmo</string>
        <string>mix</string>
    </array>
    <key>targets</key>
    <dict>
        <key>color_scene</key>
        <dict>
            <key>type</key>
            <string>color</string>
        </dict>
        <key>color_gizmo</key>
        <dict>
            <key>type</key>
            <string>color</string>
        </dict>
    </dict>
    <key>symbols</key>
    <dict>
        <key>vertexSymbol</key>
        <dict>
            <key>semantic</key>
            <string>vertex</string>
        </dict>
    </dict>
</dict>
</plist>
```

The main region of interest being the `colorStates` property of the `pass_gizmo` pass never actually clearing / the camera feed is always rendered anyway;

```
<key>colorStates</key>
<dict>
<key>clearColor</key>
    <string>0 0 0 1</string>
    <key>clear</key>
    <true/>
</dict>
```

Answer (score 1):

I eventually managed to find a way to create the object silhouette shader that I wanted. It not quite as elegant as I was hoping to achieve, but it is the only solution that I could get to work within ARKit.

I never managed to solve my original issue, but I suspect it was to do with a dodgy combination of input/outputs on my passes.

If anyone stumbles upon this in future wanting to create a similar effect, I achieved it with the 3 pass SCNTechnique described below:

- Pass 1, `DRAW_SCENE` draw the scene as usual. color output to COLOR and depth output to DEPTH
- Pass 2, `DRAW_SCENE + category mask` draw the depth of my gizmo to a depth target: `gizmo_depth`
- Pass 3, `DRAW_QUAD` custom metal fragment shader that compares the scene depth and the gizmo depth to find the hidden geometry and then multiplies the color of the scene to create a silhouette effect.

It's unfortunate that `SCNTechnique` is such a hassle to work with because I generally quite like the format. I struggled a lot with sequential passes not sharing targets between each other even though I'm sure they were correctly defined in the targets.